# What Is The Correct Way of Closing / Disconnecting An ASP.NET Core signalR Client Connection?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am a new user struggling to close a secondary signalR client gracefully from an ASP.NET Core Blazor Server Page.

I am setting up a secondary signalR client connection on first render of a Blazor Server Page. I am trying to close this secondary signalR client connection when the Page is closed via the browser tab.

At the time of writing `DisposeAsync` does not seem to be triggered when the page is closed via the browser tab. However, the `Dispose` method *IS* triggered. Furthermore in Safari 13.0.5 the `Dispose` method is not triggered when the browser tab is closed? Opera, Firefox and Chrome all have `Dispose` triggered upon closing the browser tab. Fixed this by updating Safari to v14.0 (15610.1.28.9, 15610) via macOS Catalina v10.15.7.

Currently, I am calling `DisposeAsync` from `Dispose` to close the signalR connection. I am closing the client connection using the following code:

```
...
Logger.LogInformation("Closing secondary signalR connection...");
await hubConnection.StopAsync();
Logger.LogInformation("Closed secondary signalR connection");
...
```

The `StopAsync` method appears to block, i.e. no message is output for *"Closed secondary signalR connection"*. Although, the `OnDisconnectedAsync` handler of my server hub displays that the connection has being disconnected. This is similar to the [behaviour](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9893#issuecomment-491998333) described in this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9893).

How do I correctly dispose of a signalR connection in **ASP.NET Core 3.1**?

Full code listings are shown below:

**Disposing Of signalR Connection**

```
 #region Dispose
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Clear secondary signalR Closed event handler and stop the
        /// secondary signalR connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// ASP.NET Core Release Candidate 5 calls DisposeAsync when 
        /// navigating away from a Blazor Server page. Until the 
        /// release is stable DisposeAsync will have to be triggered from
        /// Dispose. Sadly, this means having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        /// in Dispose().
        /// However, providing DisposeAsync() now makes the migration easier
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26737
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9960
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/milestone/57?closed=1
        /// </remarks>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Index.razor page is disposing...");

                try
                {
                    if (hubConnection != null)
                    {
                        Logger.LogInformation("Removing signalR client event handlers...");
                        hubConnection.Closed -= CloseHandler;
                    }

                    // Until ASP.NET Core 5 is released in November
                    // trigger DisposeAsync(). See docstring and DiposeAsync() below.
                    // not ideal, but having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() until
                    // forthcoming release of ASP.NET Core 5 for the introduction
                    // of triggering DisposeAsync on pages that implement IAsyncDisposable
                    DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Logger.LogError($"Exception encountered while disposing Index.razor page :: {exception.Message}");
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose the secondary backend signalR connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// ASP.NET Core Release Candidate 5 adds DisposeAsync when 
        /// navigating away from a Blazor Server page. Until the 
        /// release is stable DisposeAsync will have to be triggered from
        /// Dispose. Sadly, this means having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        /// in Dispose().
        /// However, providing DisposeAsync() now makes the migration easier
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26737
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9960
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/milestone/57?closed=1
        /// </remarks>
        public async virtual ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (hubConnection != null)
                {
                    Logger.LogInformation("Closing secondary signalR connection...");
                    await hubConnection.StopAsync();
                    Logger.LogInformation("Closed secondary signalR connection");
                }
                // Dispose(); When migrated to ASP.NET Core 5 let DisposeAsync trigger Dispose
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"Exception encountered wwhile stopping secondary signalR connection :: {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**Full Code For Blazor Server Page**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters;
using WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters.Visitors;
using WebApp.Repository.Contracts;



namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    public partial class Index : IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
    {
        private HubConnection hubConnection;
        public bool IsConnected => hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
        private bool disposed = false;


        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public IMotionDetectionRepository Repository { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter> LoggerMotionDetection { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public ILogger<MotionInfoConverter> LoggerMotionInfo { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public ILogger<JsonVisitor> LoggerJsonVisitor { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public ILogger<Index> Logger { get; set; }


        #region Dispose
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Clear secondary signalR Closed event handler and stop the
        /// secondary signalR connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// ASP.NET Core Release Candidate 5 calls DisposeAsync when 
        /// navigating away from a Blazor Server page. Until the 
        /// release is stable DisposeAsync will have to be triggered from
        /// Dispose. Sadly, this means having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        /// in Dispose().
        /// However, providing DisposeAsync() now makes the migration easier
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26737
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9960
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/milestone/57?closed=1
        /// </remarks>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Index.razor page is disposing...");

                try
                {
                    if (hubConnection != null)
                    {
                        Logger.LogInformation("Removing signalR client event handlers...");
                        hubConnection.Closed -= CloseHandler;
                    }

                    // Until ASP.NET Core 5 is released in November
                    // trigger DisposeAsync(). See docstring and DiposeAsync() below.
                    // not ideal, but having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() until
                    // forthcoming release of ASP.NET Core 5 for the introduction
                    // of triggering DisposeAsync on pages that implement IAsyncDisposable
                    DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Logger.LogError($"Exception encountered while disposing Index.razor page :: {exception.Message}");
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose the secondary backend signalR connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// ASP.NET Core Release Candidate 5 adds DisposeAsync when 
        /// navigating away from a Blazor Server page. Until the 
        /// release is stable DisposeAsync will have to be triggered from
        /// Dispose. Sadly, this means having to use GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        /// in Dispose().
        /// However, providing DisposeAsync() now makes the migration easier
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26737
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9960
        /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/milestone/57?closed=1
        /// </remarks>
        public async virtual ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (hubConnection != null)
                {
                    Logger.LogInformation("Closing secondary signalR connection...");
                    await hubConnection.StopAsync();
                    Logger.LogInformation("Closed secondary signalR connection");
                }
                // Dispose(); When migrated to ASP.NET Core 5 let DisposeAsync trigger Dispose
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"Exception encountered wwhile stopping secondary signalR connection :: {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region ComponentBase

        /// <summary>
        /// Connect to the secondary signalR hub after rendering.
        /// Perform on the first render. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This could have been performed in OnInitializedAsync but
        /// that method gets executed twice when server prerendering is used.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                var hubUrl = NavigationManager.BaseUri.TrimEnd('/') + "/motionhub";

                try
                {
                    Logger.LogInformation("Index.razor page is performing initial render, connecting to secondary signalR hub");

                    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .WithUrl(hubUrl)
                        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                        {
                            logging.AddConsole();
                            logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Information);
                        })
                        .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
                        {
                            options.PayloadSerializerOptions = JsonConvertersFactory.CreateDefaultJsonConverters(LoggerMotionDetection, LoggerMotionInfo, LoggerJsonVisitor);
                        })
                        .Build();

                    hubConnection.On<MotionDetection>("ReceiveMotionDetection", ReceiveMessage);
                    hubConnection.Closed += CloseHandler;

                    Logger.LogInformation("Starting HubConnection");

                    await hubConnection.StartAsync();

                    Logger.LogInformation("Index Razor Page initialised, listening on signalR hub url => " + hubUrl.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(e, "Encountered exception => " + e);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        #endregion


        #region signalR

        /// <summary>Log signalR connection closing</summary>
        /// <param name="exception">
        /// If an exception occurred while closing then this argument describes the exception
        /// If the signaR connection was closed intentionally by client or server, then this
        /// argument is null
        /// </param>
        private Task CloseHandler(Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception == null)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("signalR client connection closed");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"signalR client closed due to error => {exception.Message}");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add motion detection notification to repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Motion detection received via signalR</param>
        private void ReceiveMessage(MotionDetection message)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Motion detection message received");

                Repository.AddItem(message);

                StateHasChanged();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex, "An exception was encountered => " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**signalR Server Hub**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace WebApp.Realtime.SignalR
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This represents endpoints available on the server, available for the
    /// clients to call
    /// </summary>
    public class MotionHub : Hub<IMotion>
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        public ILogger<MotionHub> Logger { get; set; }

        public MotionHub(ILogger<MotionHub> logger) : base()
        {
            Logger = logger;
        }


        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"OnConnectedAsync => Connection ID={Context.ConnectionId} : User={Context.User.Identity.Name}");
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception != null)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"OnDisconnectedAsync => Connection ID={Context.ConnectionId} : User={Context.User.Identity.Name} : Exception={exception.Message}");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"OnDisconnectedAsync => Connection ID={Context.ConnectionId} : User={Context.User.Identity.Name}");
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            _disposed = true;

            // Call base class implementation.
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use try-Catch-Finally syntax to close/dispose the connection. Like this: `try{ await hubConnection.StopAsync(); } catch (Exception exception) { Logger.LogInformation(exception.Message);} finally { await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();}`.

Comment: I suppose perhaps it is related that the CloseAsync is called from within Dispose, the state is already set to disposed when reaching, so it might through an exception, check [Blazor wasm SignalR does not close the connection ](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/18628) and [Best practice to dispose SignalR HubConnection in .NET Core ](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13082).

Comment: Thanks @zhi-liv Good advice. Tried placing the exception handling block around ```hubConnection.StopAsync()```. No exception is thrown. It looks like it is blocking on ```StopAsync```.  Asked [question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/27077#discussioncomment-107052) on github discussions and after changing ```DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();``` to ```_ = DisposeAsync()``` within ```Dispose``` method it works. Not sure why though? Waiting for follow up answer on gihub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed with help from [ASP.NET Core Github Discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/27077#discussioncomment-107052).

Within the `Dispose` method replaced `DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); to _ = DisposeAsync();` This calls `DiposeAsync()` without awaiting the task result.

Also updated my code that stops the hub connection:

```
  try { await hubConnection.StopAsync(); }
  finally
  {
    await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
  }
```

Within `DisposeAsync` the `StopAsync` call on the `HubConnection` no longer blocks and the connection closes gracefully.

Comment: Glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.